# jQuery Sortable with collapsed content

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

I want to use jQuery sortable function to all a user to arrange boxes. Simple enough. The boxes can get quite tall, however, so when they click on the handle to sort, I'd like all of the boxes to collapse. I got something working (shown below). When you try sorting the first row, everything works great. But anything below that and it gets a little weird.

First off, is there a better way to do this that I'm not thinking of?

Second, if I'm staying with this code, is there a way to make sure the now collapsed div that is select snaps to and stays with the mouse? If you look at it now, when you select a div not from the first row, the selected div is a lot higher than where the mouse is (because of the collapsing).

The jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cwv9usqf/5/

```
$('.header').mousedown(function(){ $('.content').hide(); })

$('.container').sortable({
  connectWith: '.container',
  items: '.portlet',
  handle: '.header',
  tolerance: 'pointer',
  stop: function(){ $('.content').show(); }
});
```

Another note: right now when you simply click on the header, the portlets collapse. Is there a way I can only have them collapse when the drag is happening?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I updated the Fiddle with a few things: The portlets weren't always re-opening, so I added an event on 'stop' for the sortable to fix this. I also set the tolerance so at least the functionality would work as expect. Visually it's still wrong though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out:

(updated Fiddle) http://jsfiddle.net/cwv9usqf/6/

```
$('.container').sortable({
  connectWith: '.container',
  items: '.portlet',
  handle: '.header',
  tolerance: 'pointer',
  revert: true,
  placeholder: 'placeholder',
  start: function(){ $('.content').hide(); },
  stop: function(){ $('.content').show(); }
});
```

I added the 'start' option to it and removed the mousedown/mouseup listeners all together.

Comment: Dude, if you collapse the first itemon the start event and drag doen on the y axis, the position is only updated whe you reach the last item. I am facing the same problem, and I think it's a library bug.
Your first example was better.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things:

1. I made your elements unselectable that way you don't accidentally highlight it.
2. I changed it to an unordered list, to remove repetitive code.
3. I made the cursor to a pointer as that is pretty standard for intractable items.
4. I used flex instead of px values for the sake of making a dynamic webpage.

```js
$("#sortable").sortable({
  revert: true
});
```

```css
#sortable { 
  width: 100%; 
  list-style-type:none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-user-select: none; /* Chrome/Safari */        
  -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
  -ms-user-select: none; /* IE10+ */
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#sortable > li {
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="demo">
    <div>
        <ul id="sortable">
          <li>Home</li>
          <li>Contact Us</li>
          <li>About</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry - I posted the wrong jsFiddle. The one you were looking at was where I got some references from. Please check the updated link.